# Defining coordinates in `foreach`

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want to define in a `\foreach` loop a bunch of coordinates in terms of previously defined coordinates:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A0) at (0,0);
        
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
            \def\j{\i-1}
            \coordinate (A\i) at A(\j)+(5*\i,\i*\i);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this does not seem to work, because (as I understand it), TikZ does not evaluate `\j-1`. Is there a way to fix this? I would like to avoid copy pasting the same code over and over again.

Comment: To be sure, do you need A1 at (5,1) and A2 at (15,5) ? I would compute the coordinates in a \path and set the point during the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `evaluate`.

And I suppose that with `A(\j)` you intended `(A\j)`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A0) at (0,0);
        \foreach[evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i-1)] \i in {1,...,10}{
            \coordinate (A\i) at (A\j)+(5*\i,\i*\i);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution who relies on computing `\i-1` previously to correctly define `(A\j)` by using `\pgfmathparse` and `\pgfmathresult`.

The translation by `(5*\i,\i*\i)` are shifted with the corresponding options.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A0) at (0,0);
        
        \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
            \pgfmathparse{\i-1}
            \def\j{\pgfmathresult}
            \coordinate (A\i) at ([xshift={5*\i}, yshift={\i*\i}]A\j);
%Test
%           \node (A\i) at ([xshift={5*\i}, yshift={\i*\i}]A\j);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```